# Symbolic: Rearrange so one side is zero

Tags: matlab, symengine

I have the equation:

```
syms x y
A= 5*x - 100*y == x
```

I want it to be rearranged in the form:

```
A = 0 == 4*x-100y
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `children()` to split `A` in two parts:

- Left Hand Side:  `LHS`
- Right Hand Side:  `RHS`

Then compute `A = 0 == LHS - RHS`

**The code is as follows**

```
syms x y

A = 5*x - 100*y == x;

A_as_Array = children(A);

A_Left_Hand_Side = A_as_Array(1) ;

A_Right_Hand_Side = A_as_Array(2); 

A = 0 == A_Left_Hand_Side - A_Right_Hand_Side; 

% A = 0 == 4*x - 100*y
```